# Detect if Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides is installed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to detect if 
['Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en) 
is installed in Chrome from javascript running in a webpage (not in extension) ?

If it is installed, we want to open and edit the document in a new tab,
while if it is not installed, we want to download the document in CURRENT tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just digged into the source code of this extension, and found it has the following entries in `manifest.json`

```
"web_accessible_resources": [ "views/app.html", "views/qowt.html" ]
```

So you can detect if the extension is installed by querying if `views/app.html` exists. Just make an ajax call and check the xhr status.

```
function detectExtension(extensionId, successCallback, failCallback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                successCallback();
            } else {
                failCallback();
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "chrome-extension://" + extensionId + "/views/app.html");
    xhr.send();
}

detectExtension("gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj", function() {
    console.log("The extension is installed");
}, function() {
    console.log("The extension is not installed");
});
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that Google does not have an API published for these files so they could disappear at anytime breaking detection.

Comment: @abraham, yes, you're right, this method is a little tricky and may be invalid at some time. But considering there is no official api to use, it seems to be a workaround at present.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. Hopefully Google will add an official api/callback to check if the extension is installed.